# The TH sound seems to be silent just after the S sound

Tags: pronunciation, consonants, silent-letter, consonant-clusters

When enjoying this beautiful song, I can't help but ask a question just like why the TH sound of that seems silent when used after the S sound. In my brain, the sound formed itself "recklessat" just as if there was no TH sound. I'm not sure how this combination pronounces and wonder whether my ears have got any problems or it's just about Taylor Swift who enjoys performing this  melody in this particular way.

This is about a excerpt from a lyrics of Sparks Fly by Taylor Swift.

> The way you move is like a full on rainstorm And I'm a house of cards
>   You're the kinda **reckless that** should send me running  But I kinda know
>   that I won't get far And you stood there in front of me just Close
>   enough to touch Close enough to hope you couldn't See what I was
>   thinking of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal, not peculiar to Ms. Swift. In speech *th-* is often assimilated to an immediately preceding continuant, not only with *that* but at the onset of any unstressed function word such as *the*, *this*, *they*, *them*.

Comment: When speaking fast, can I speak recklessat directly?

Comment: @繹SIMA夏目 Many native speakers do. This does not mean, however, that you should emulate their speech--for instance, in an effort to sound more like a native. There are far more important matters to be concerned with, such as the tonal and rhythmic contour of your speech.

Comment: I'm certainly no AAVE speaker, so I probably wouldn't say ***Dat's what I'm talking about!*** very often. But if the preceding consonant is a **/d/**, as in *I think it's kinda **stupid that** we're in this position*, I'd quite naturally enunciate ***that = dat*** in casual speech (where if the ***that-*** clause weren't present, the **/d/** of ***stupid*** would normally be reduced to just a kinda glottal stop).

Comment: @FumbleFingers In US speech the /ð/ is more likely to be completely assimilated after a continuant consonant, which I think is what OP is talking about: *You still have 'ose books I gave you, or d'jou lose 'em?*

Comment: Yes, I think "unstressed function word" is the key category here, not /sð/ (or any permutation of voiced/voiceless alternatives). For example, in the word "calisthenics", I find it hard to delete /θ/ without conscious effort, whereas the /ð/ in a sufficiently rapidly pronounced "Y'ever see that movie?" is barely articulated if at all, at least here in Toronto. That said, assimilation obviously is a factor in many similar deletions, even if it's aided by syntactic properties.

Comment: @StoneyB If I'm speaking carelessly enough for those consonants to disappear, the vowel in "you" changes and it sounds like "or jyuh lose 'em." And the "you" at the beginning is barely audible. It's certainly not something someone learning English should go out of their way to emulate!

Comment: @StoneyB what is the original version of d'jou ? I'm not very clear about this.

Comment: @繹SIMA夏目 *or did you*

Comment: @StoneyB I know it's not a easy work but I still want to know how to get familiar with those pronunciation rules that are not very formal for the purpose of recognizing them when I hear next time.